# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая с помощью `for` проходит по списку и выводит название штата и количество букв в нем.

```
newEngland = ["Maine","New Hampshire","Vermont", "Rhode Island", 
"Massachusetts","Connecticut"]


def how_many_let(ne):
    lis=ne
    for i in lis:
        num_let=len(lis[i])
        print(i,' has',num_let,' letters')
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Я не знаю, как исправить эту ошибку. Буду благодарна за любую помощь.

Comment: Ну, во-первых это ru.stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow на русском), во-вторых вы через for итерируетесь по списку `lis`, а список `lis` - это список строк. Соответственно, в `i` попадает строка, отсюда ошибка, что `i` (строку) нельзя использовать в качестве индекса (`lis[i]`)

Comment: def problem2_3(ne):
    lis=ne
    for i in range(0,6):
        num_let=len(lis[i])
        print(i,' has',num_let,' letters')      Функция работает теперь,но штаты в виде чисел.

Comment: def problem2_3(ne):
    for i in range(0,len(ne)):
        num_let=len(ne[i])
        print(ne[i],' has',num_let,' letters')  - получилось )

Comment: Ну `range` тут тоже не нужен, без него вполне работает.

Answer (score 2):

Вы с помощью `for` проходите по списку `lis`, а список `lis` - это список строк. Соответственно, в `i` попадает строка, отсюда ошибка, что `i` (строку) нельзя использовать в качестве индекса (`lis[i]`). В вашем случае индексы вообще не нужны, просто учитывайте, что при проходе по списку вы получаете сами строки из списка, а не индексы:

```
def how_many_let(ne):
    lis=ne
    for word in lis:
        num_let=len(word)
        print(word, 'has', num_let, 'letters')
```

Еще пара моментов:

1. Обратите внимание, что при присваивании `lis=ne` не происходит копирование списка. В принципе эта операция тут и не нужна, но зачем-то вы же ее вставили, поэтому на всякий случай предупреждаю)
2. При выводе через `print` нескольких аргументов между ними автоматически вставляются пробелы. Дополнительные пробелы в строках `'has'` и `'letters'` в данном случае не нужны.

Если все-таки вдруг понадобятся еще и индексы строк, можно воспользоваться функцией `enumerate`:

```
for i, word in enumerate(lis):  # в word попадает строка из списка, а в i - ее индекс
    ...
```

Comment: def problem2_3(ne):
    for i in range(0,len(ne)):
        num_let=len(ne[i])
        print(ne[i],' has',num_let,' letters')   --- спасибо за совет. получилось

Comment: попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
SPISOK_GORODOV = ["Maine","New Hampshire","Vermont", "Rhode Island",
"Massachusetts","Connecticut"]

for GOROD in SPISOK_GORODOV:
    DLINA_GORODA=len(GOROD)
    print(GOROD, 'has', DLINA_GORODA, 'letters')
```

В вашем коде обрабатывается не индекс i, а конкретно каждый элемент списка, в данном случае строки. Похоже на то, что при написании этого цикла, вы руководствовались логикой других языков программирования.

Comment: А ЗАЧЕМ ВСЕ В ВЕРХНЕМ РЕГИСТРЕ? :)

Comment: Чтобы понятней было. ))) Аххах. Я смотрел уроки Web2Py И там чувак сказал мол: Давайте увеличим размер кода, чтобы было понятней и чуть ли не на весь экран одну строку сделал. Оттуда и пошел прикол.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def count_letters(name):
    for one in name:
        name_len = len(one) - one.count(" ")  #кол-во букв в названии, не считая пробелы 
        print(f'{one} contains {name_len} letters in name')

newEngland = ["Maine","New Hampshire","Vermont", "Rhode Island","Massachusetts",
"Connecticut"]

count_letters(newEngland)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Так то лучше:

```
def let(n):
    for i in range(len(n)):
        print(n[i],len(n[i]))

n = ["Maine","New Hampshire","Vermont", "Rhode Island", "Massachusetts","Connecticut"]
let(n)
```